# Attempting to datascrape from ASX website table

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

I have been trying to data scrape the current value of a stock from the ASX.com.au website. Namely, I am trying to grab the current value of the ASX. This can be found here.

http://www.asx.com.au/asx/markets/equityPrices.do?by=asxCodes&asxCodes=asx

It is the second td from the left, at the time of writing this it is sitting at 30.410.

I can played around with some code and have not been able to get it to work.

Below is the sample code I have been toying with, if anyone is able to help me to get this to work I would be grateful!

```
<?php

$data = file_get_contents('http://www.asx.com.au/asx/markets/equityPrices.do?by=asxCodes&asxCodes=asx');

$asx = explode('<th class="row" scope="row">ASX: </th>', $data);
$asx = substr($asx[1], 4, strpos($asx[1], '</td>') - 4);

?><div class="asxvalue"><?php echo $asx . "<br />\n";?></div>
```

**EDIT**

Update of code

```
<?php

$data = file_get_contents('http://www.asx.com.au/asx/research/companyInfo.do?by=asxCode&asxCode=DTL');

preg_match('/<td class="last">([^<]*?)</td>/i',$data,$matches);
$valueYouWant = $matches[1];

?><div class="data"><?php echo $valueYouWant ?></div>
```

Comment: http://www.asx.com.au/legal/terms-use.htm *You must not use any spider, screen scraper, robot, or other automated similar software or device ("Prohibited Device") to use or access the Site in any way whatsoever, nor can you use any Prohibited Device (or any similar process) to copy, download or monitor the Content, without ASX’s prior written approval.*

Comment: Ah, I definitely should have checked this out. Thankyou for that!

For learning purposes would it be okay for you to help me with the code, if I never actually implement it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everyone will rightfully tell you that you can't parse html with regex and should use an html parser (like this one at [simple_dom](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/)) but for your specific problem you can do this:

```
preg_match('/<td class="last">([^<]*?)</td>/i',$data,$matches);
$valueYouWant = $matches[1];
```

To find the value of the date and last on the other page you can use the following:
I actually would suggest using Simple_Dom for things like this in the future but until you are comfortable with it this will work for now:

```
$data = file_get_contents('http://www.asx.com.au/asx/research/companyInfo.do?by=asxCode&asxCode=DTL');
preg_match('/id="closing-prices".*?<strong>(.*?)<\/strong>.*?<td class="last">(.*?)<\/td>/s',$data,$matches);
$date = $matches[1]; 
$lastValue = $matches[2];
```

I have tested this and it works.  To make it more robust I recommend using other tools but this should get you off the ground. Good Luck!

Comment: I see, I will looking into the simple_dom now. How would I go about implementing the code that you just posted?

I tried wrapping it in php tags and putting an echo $valueYouWant; but it just returned php errors.

Comment: You should be able to put it right after your line where $data is defined... what errors did it print? Maybe your php configuration doesn't have the preg functions somehow?

Comment: Oh I see, I didn't include the $data line >_<

I will take a look at this again on Monday :) Thanks for your help!

Comment: Sure thing.  If that doesn't work for you I can give it to you with another function or the simple_dom code.  If you do get it to work can you up vote or accept my answer?  Thanks.

Comment: Yeah for sure, whatever you can give me will be amazing! I'll upvote you when it works for sure :) Have to give props where props are due!!!

Comment: Okay, so it still isn't working. This is what I tried, are you able to shed some light on it please?

<?php

$data = file_get_contents('http://www.asx.com.au/asx/research/companyInfo.do?by=asxCode&asxCode=DTL');

preg_match('/<td class="last">([^<]*?)</td>/i',$data,$matches);
$valueYouWant = $matches[1];

?><div class="data"><?php echo $valueYouWant ?></div>

Comment: well what is the output? Do you have error messages? also it looks like you forgot the semicolon on the echo statement and the http:// on the link (always have the full http:// in the path for file_get_contents calls).

Comment: Warning: preg_match() [function.preg-match]: Unknown modifier 't' <- that is the error!

I added the semicolon to the echo, and it has the http in the php, I think stackoverflow trims it off.

Comment: oh sorry that was my fault. you have to escape the / so it should be preg_match('/<td class="last">([^<]*?)<\/td>/i',$data,$matches);

Comment: Awesome :) That works a treat!

I'll mark this one as answered and upvote all your comments :)!

Just another question for you, how would I go about expanding that so that it got data from the table below. The closing prices table

13 Feb 2012 | 1.330 

Or whatever the most recent data is :)?

Comment: Sorry, what tables are you referring to?  Of course I can help you on this one, but I would suggest you read up on regular expressions and/or get comfortable with simple_dom so that you know how to do this for your future projects.  (Also accepting the answer and voting it up are different, to accept the answer click the green check mark.)

Comment: The table slightly lower on the page... The text just above it is
"Closing prices

Closing prices are displayed for the last 5 days on which the security traded on ASX within the last 6 months."

Then it has the first column as 'Date', the second column as 'Last'

I wish to be able to grab the value for the most recent date, and last (the top td)

Do you know any books or anything I could buy to get a bit more comfortable with simple_dom? Or is it too small for a book?

Comment: Sorry didn't realize you meant on the page http://www.asx.com.au/asx/research/companyInfo.do?by=asxCode&asxCode=DTL I was looking at http://www.asx.com.au/asx/markets/equityPrices.do?by=asxCodes&asxCodes=asx still trying to find it. I am editing my answer above for the code.  Simple dom wouldn't have a book on it but everything about how to use it can be found [here](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for this - I was able to use the code in a Wordpress PHP Code widget and it works a treat for ASX Stock price:

```
<?php

$data = file_get_contents('http://www.asx.com.au/asx/research/companyInfo.do?by=asxCode&asxCode=asx');
preg_match('/id="closing-prices".*?<strong>(.*?)<\/strong>.*?<td class="last">(.*?)<\/td>/s',$data,$matches);
$date = $matches[1]; 
$lastValue = $matches[2];

?><div class="data">$<?php echo $lastValue ?></div>
```

Thought someone might find the above solution all put together in case it was useful.

Thanks very much for answering this question hackartist : )